# How do I fix database caching for Tauri - Rust with Diesel and SQLite?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, tauri

I am trying to build a small app with **Tauri** and **SQLite** database with **Diesel ORM** and every time I start the app with `yarn tauri dev` it will bring the first data from the migration script of the database. Even if I remove the database it will bring the same data. It feels like the data is cached somehow.

For **Cargo.toml** I have this dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
serde_json = "1.0"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
tauri = { version = "1.2.4", features = ["shell-open"] }
diesel = { version = "2.0.0", features = ["sqlite", "returning_clauses_for_sqlite_3_35"] }
libsqlite3-sys = { version = "0.25.2", features = ["bundled"] }
diesel_migrations = {version = "2.0.0", features = ["sqlite"] }
remove_dir_all = "0.8.2"
```

The method that I am using to select the data is this:

```
#[derive(Identifiable, Queryable, Serialize, Deserialize, AsChangeset)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
#[diesel(table_name = pwn_contracts)]
pub struct Contract {
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
}

pub fn contract_list(db_path: String) -> Vec<Contract> {
    let mut connection = establish_connection(&db_path);
    pwn_contracts::dsl::pwn_contracts
        .select(pwn_contracts::all_columns)
        .load::<Contract>(&mut connection)
        .expect("Loading contracts failed")
}
```

The **establish_connection** method looks like this:

```
pub fn establish_connection(path: &str) -> SqliteConnection {
    SqliteConnection::establish(path).unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Error connecting to database"))
}
```

I've tried also with this:

```
pub fn establish_connection(path: &str) -> SqliteConnection {
    SqliteConnection::establish(&format!("sqlite://{}?cache=none", path)).unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Error connecting to database"))
}
```

But I get some error.

Am I missing something? How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it only the migration data that shows up? Seems like `SqliteConnection` isn't finding the database and creating one each time you boot the app, as per [the docs](https://docs.diesel.rs/master/diesel/sqlite/struct.SqliteConnection.html#method.establish). Can you verify the `db_path` is valid and exists when you boot?

Comment: It is the migration data where I do the `INSERT INTO pwn_contracts(id, name) VALUES` with the first values (the data when I ran for the first time `diesel migration run`). But even if I update the migration script with more entries or I update the database manually the new data won't appear. If it's like you said with missing database how come that it worked for the first time. I haven't change the database path at all from the beginning.

Comment: Exactly, it's not loading the database you're expecting it to load. And it worked the first time because it's always loaded that now orphaned DB. Have you run `cargo clean`? It's most likely created the sqlite db in your `target/{release_type}` folder.

Comment: Try and search your project/target folder for any file with `*.sqlite*`. You might find a few?

Comment: Yes, I ran `cargo clean` before posting the question with the same outcome. In `src-tauri/target` there are `debug, .rustc_info.json and CACHEDIR.TAG`. Have in mind please that after I ran for the first time the app, the data that is displayed now (that I believe is cached) appeared also in **TablePlus**. Where it is this **orphan db** that you said, how do I find it?

Comment: Not trying to be rude, just making sure you did some basic things that could mess you up. What I'm saying is that I have no idea where the DB your code connecting to exists. It wouldn't be cached, because the DB itself exists on the filesystem. So you're most likely loading it from somewhere you don't expect. I could be completely wrong! Look in `target/debug` in your tauri build? Can you verify you don't have other sqlite dbs laying around in the project? Something like `find . -name "*.sqlite3"?`

Comment: If you're 100% sure that's the db you're loading from then maybe ask this in the diesel/tauri github issues.

Comment: Also I found this https://reactjsexample.com/tauri-demo-app-using-rust-and-react/, look at the section about sqlite rebuilding each time you compile!

Comment: Yes, I used `find . -name "*.sqlite*"` and there are no results in the **Tauri** project. The only result is in the parent of the tauri project where is the database that I am trying to use and it's not linking to the project. I will try to take a look over there, and ask on the **github**

Comment: @SeedyROM I followed your advice and discussed on **Tauri Discord** server and someone offered some support. The problem is not related with **Tauri** is more oriented in the **Diesel** direction. It created a .sqlite3 database on a different path on my local machine. I will update the post for a more relevant description